# CircularFloatingActionMenu in Fragment of ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment

In my android application I have ViewPager with some Fragments. I wanted to use and show Circular Floating Action Button Menu in one of this Fragments but FAB somehow visiable in all Fragments. How to solve this problem and show FAB only in one Fragment. By the way it is that library: [github](https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu)

**Fragment.java**

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Floating Action Button
        //Create a button to attach the menu
        ImageView movieFAB = new ImageView(getActivity());
        movieFAB.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        //Create menu items
        FloatingActionButton actionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(getActivity()).setContentView(movieFAB).build();
        ImageView iconSortName = new ImageView(getActivity());
        iconSortName.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star);
        ImageView iconSortDate = new ImageView(getActivity());
        iconSortDate.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_cloud);
        ImageView iconSortRatings = new ImageView(getActivity());
        iconSortRatings.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_communication);

        SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(getActivity());
        SubActionButton buttonSortName = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconSortName).build();
        SubActionButton buttonSortDate = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconSortDate).build();
        SubActionButton buttonSortRatings = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconSortRatings).build();

        //Create the menu with the items
        FloatingActionMenu actionMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(getActivity())
                .addSubActionView(buttonSortName)
                .addSubActionView(buttonSortDate)
                .addSubActionView(buttonSortRatings)
                .attachTo(actionButton)
                .build();
    }
```

**Thanks for any help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create implementation of `OnPageChangeListener` where override onPageSelected method.

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (position == VALID_POSITION) {
        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        fabMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Then set it to the viewPager

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(....);
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thank you man, nice idea! Пасибі. You know, I want to add one effect may be you know how to add it. Let me try to explaine it to you. When user srcoll that fragment with FAB it go away to right side as here. https://github.com/shell-software/fab/blob/master/demo/animation_jump_from_right_jump_to_right.gif?raw=true Do you have any ideas how to make that?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly how my OnPageChangeListener is set up. I did exactly what @Eldar Mensutov did, but also made sure to hide the buttons! In my specific case below, I only wanted the menu to show up on my second fragment (pageNumber == 1), and hidden for every other fragment:

```
           mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int pageNumber) {
                    if (pageNumber == 1) {
                        actionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        button5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        actionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        button3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        button4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        button5.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    if(pageNumber == 0) {
                        TextView textElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                        textElement.setText("Fragment 1 Title");

                        // Do stuff here

                    }
                    if(pageNumber == 1) {
                        TextView textElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                        textElement.setText("Fragment 2 Title");

                        // Do stuff here

                    }
                    else if(pageNumber == 2) {
                        TextView textElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                        textElement.setText("Fragment 3 Title");

                        // Do stuff here

                    }

                    else if(pageNumber == 3) {
                        TextView textElement = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
                        textElement.setText("Fragment 4 Title");

                        // Do stuff here

                    }
                }    
            }
```